# Prevent Submit in Jquery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Jquery File Upload(http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and Bootstrap validator(https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator) in my page and I only need to upload files on server if form is valid,Hence I override the default submit functionality of  Jquery-File-Upload as following

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.fileupload').fileupload({
                    url: '/upload',
                    autoupload: false,
                    dropZone: $(".fileuploadzone"),
                    submit: function (e) {
                        $(document).bootstrapValidator('validate');
                        if ($(document).data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                });
                $('.fileupload').bind('fileuploadfinished', function (e, data) {

                   submitForm();

                });
   });
```

It works for the first click of submit button('valid' or 'invalid'),but doesn't work afterwards even if form is valid .
I mean neither validation nor File Upload process is performed.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to reset the bootstrap validator after each form submission.

```
$('.fileupload').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem with you,

**If the submit event callback returns false, the upload request will not start. ([enter link description here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options))

Here is my solution.
when submit callback return false the start button was disabled, I try to remove "disabled" attribute in submit callback and it work fine for me.

```
submit: function(){
//---invalid--
$('button.start').removeAttr('disabled');
return false;
}
```

Good luck.